# Assign string to Dictionary

Tags: swift

I have this one:

```
var str:[String] = ["John:Computer Engineer","Melinda:Saler"]
```

and i want to assign to that

```
var myDictVal:[String:String]?
..... 
Doing some operation. After done, the value of myDictVal will be:
myDictVal = ["John":"Computer" , "Melinda":"Saler"]
```

how I can assign string array to Dictionary variable? 
Sorry for my english. Typing on my iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work, although you probably should add some sort of validation to make sure your strings have the proper format, especially if you're getting them from user input.

```
var stringArray:[String] = ["John:Computer Engineer", "Melinda:Saler"]

var myDictVal:[String:String] = Dictionary<String, String>()

for item in stringArray {

    var myArray = item.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

    var name:String = myArray[0]
    var title:String = myArray[1]
    myDictVal[name] = title

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing that - the solution I would choose is:

- loop through all array elements, split each element by `:`, and create an array of (key, value) tuples
- loop through all tuples, add to the dictionary

  ```
  var res = str.map { (element: String) -> (key: String, value: String) in
      var components = element.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
      return (key: components[0], value: components[1])
  }

  for (key, value) in res {
      myDictVal?[key] = value
  }
  ```

Note that this version can throw a runtime exception if any of the array elements doesn't have the `key:value` format.